# Package data with relative path

Tags: python, file, path, working-directory, data-files

I'm writing a graphical application which will depend on a language file containing text snippets in different languages for the UI elements.

I want to store these files in a `lang/` directory inside the package directory which is imported by the main application script when executed.

However, I can't use `./` when opening the language files for reading, because `./` is the working directory of the user, not the location of the imported Python file.

With a source structure that looks like

```
/
-- mypkg/
   -- lang/
      -- en_US.lang
      -- es_ES.lang
      -- <etc...>
   -- __init__.py
   -- lang.py
-- myapp (executable Python script which imports mypkg)
```

how can I reliably read from the `lang/` directory without relying on a particular working directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the variable - `__file__` - this stores the path of the script which is being run. (This is the path which was used in the `python command`) , example if you used the following command to run the script -

```
python /complete/path/to/script.py
```

`__file__` would contain `'/complete/path/to/script.py'` . If relative path was used, it would contain the relative path to script .

Using this , you should be able to load the language files.

You can also use the function - `os.path.abspath()` to get the absolute path of the script -

```
import os.path
os.path.abspath(__file__)
```